# Python class with tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to learn the classes in Python.

I wrote a little code with tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class window():
    def __init__(self, size, title, ):
        self.size = size
        self.title = title

        window = Tk()
        window.geometry(self.size)
        window.title(self.title)

        print('a window has been created')

        window.mainloop()


    def button(self, window, text, x, y):

        self.window = window
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        button = Button(window, text=text).place(x=str(x), y=str(y))
```

but I get the error message:

```
self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'window' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: the way to define the class is strange. how did you call it?

Comment: You need to include your full code, inc. where the line that generated the error message come from?

Comment: ```root = window('640x640', 'Root Window')``` 

```root.button(root, 'test', "0", "0")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you write `self.tk` or where you called the class. Probably, you need to add `self.` when you declare `window`.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class window:
    def __init__(self, size, title, ):
        self.size = size
        self.title = title

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry(self.size)
        self.window.title(self.title)

        print('a window has been created')
        self.window.mainloop()


    def button(self, window, text, x, y):

        self.window = window
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        button = Button(window, text=text).place(x=str(x), y=str(y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = window("500x500", "nice title") # <-- You need to call the class.
```

(If you need to declare a button, you can add this line on `__init__` function above `self.window.mainloop()`: `self.button(self.window, "Title", 10, 20)`)

Answer (score 1):

you have to say from which file is this function or object is from

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
```

Comment: He need to import also `Button`, the better way is to import tkinter like this: `import tkinter as tk` and then change the code.

Comment: yes that changes code to window = tk.Tk() he still needs to give the file name. even for the button